# How to set default text in dropdownlist after binding the dropdown graphically

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am trying to set the default text into the dropdown list that should appear on top
And i have bind the dropdown to sql table graphically
here is the code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="countryDropDownList" runat="server" DataSourceID="countrySqlDataSource" DataTextField="CountryName" DataValueField="CountryId" Height="25px" Width="187px" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>    

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="countrySqlDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:123FlashChat %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblCountry]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: After binding you can set the dropdown selected index to 0 if you want the first item to be default.

Comment: How can i do it, can you please write some code

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your SelectCommand to:

```
Select -1 as Value, '--Select--' as Text
union
SELECT * FROM [tblCountry]
```

or add it as ListItem

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="countryDropDownList" runat="server" DataSourceID="countrySqlDataSource" DataTextField="CountryName" DataValueField="CountryId" Height="25px" Width="187px" AutoPostBack="True">
 <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value ="-1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use Jquery:

try something like this inside of a script tag on your page:

$("#<%=countryDropDownList.ClientID%>").val("thevalue");

where "thevalue" is the value of the item you are trying to set the selected index to